# Clear problem statement

Tags: support, on-hold

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333856/a-plan-to-make-a-fluent-interface-work-with-inheritance-w-o-casting-in-a-dry-w) seems to have been lacking a clear problem statement.  I've attempted to correct the problem by adding the following line:

"Can you fix this to allow inheritance, stay DRY, and avoid casting? Or can you prove this would never work?"

This should make the goal clear even if the page the code came from goes down.  If you still see a problem with the question feel free to let me know.  Otherwise what is the next step to remove the hold?

Comment: What you seem to be doing is dumping some code and asking someone to fix it for you... that's off on SO. It's not a code writing service nor a personal debugging help-desk etc. You may want to retake the [TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and spend a few minutes reading the [help-centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and also see [what type of questions to avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). That should be sufficient :)

Comment: According to the help they are but "must include the desired behavior"  I did that in the link, the title, and now in the body.   What more would you want to see to make the "desired behavior" more obvious?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Comment: That "must include the desired behavior" is a _necessary_ condition for a good question, but not a _sufficient_ once. Your question has to meet _all_ of those requirements, not just one requirement. Otherwise, just about anything would be a good question.

Comment: @abarnert please enlighten me as to the missing requirement(s).

Comment: @vba4all already explained what's wrong with this question. If you're _not_ just asking someone to write code for you, then your question is unclear, and your comments aren't helping, because that's what it looks like.

Comment: [See related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268118/you-are-only-half-way-there-while-trying-to-reopen-your-closed-question)

Comment: @abarnert I'm asking if a problem is solvable.  Writing code that solves it is only one way to prove it's solvable.  I posted links to other solutions that solve it but fail to meet the requirements.  I'm asking if there is a reason they HAVE to violate those requirements.  Thinking I'm asking for someone to just write code for me feels like a knee jerk reaction.  I've read your link.  I understand it's important to put myself in the shoes of my readers.  Please consider the possibility that this is simply a HARD question to answer if you haven't run into it before.  I'm hoping someone has.

Comment: @vba4all I've removed the offending code.  I assert that what remains is: "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".  Do you still see a problem?

Answer (score 10):

Your question has two distinct and both show-stopper problems. (judging from [revision no 5](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26333856/5) here)

1. Missing code.

   We can't really help you all that much without some code (at least for the question as I understood it). Linking to off-site code is... problematic. That's why there's a close-reason stating that the code  to

   > *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself.**

   You have provided no code to reproduce your problem. (close-vote 1)
2. Problem statement.

   Quoting your question:

   > Can Joshua Bloch's Builder pattern be modified to allow inheritance, stay DRY, and avoid casting? Or can you prove this would never work?

   This problem statement is problematic for two reasons... For one you are asking quite a lot of things at once, and then you include the possibility for a complete disproval.

   Additionally your Question is a **design** question. These were off-topic for SO last time I checked, mainly because they are inherently opinion based (and often asked too broad or completely unclear). [Programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) allows such questions to an extent, but be aware, discussions and open-ended questions aren't tolerated over there.

In summary your question "fails" the on-topic criteria at least twice, and thus was closed.